# Where does google cloud platform install wordpress when using template?

Tags: wordpress, google-app-engine

I have a google cloud compute engine instance with wordpress installed from their template. Where exactly do they install wordpress?

Comment: Did you use the Cloud Launcher to deploy the WordPress site? If yes was it bitnami install or Google's?

Answer (score 0):

Google Cloud Launcher installs Wordpress within `var/www/html` you can access this by SSH'ing onto your server.